# trigger events in background with android push notificacions

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I need to know if I make  when the smartphone receives a push notification, this notification isn´t show to user, but the smartphone begin to send to web server the gps location.
sorry for my really bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what ever you want when receiving a push notification by the **BroadcastReceiver**

```
 @Override
protected void onMessageReceived(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //i suppose sendGPS is the function that let you send your location
    sendGPS();
}
```